# EF4 referential integrity exception using code first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have a VERY simple model as seen here:

```
public class Cases
    {
    //case data model for call center
    //implement lists for all related child tables too

    [Key]
    public int CasesID { get; set; }

    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer is Required")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }  //get user name from the aspnet membership

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Case Category is Required")]
    public int CaseCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Technician is Required")]
    public int TechnicianID { get; set; }
    public Technician Technicians { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Engine Model is Required")]
    public int EngineModelID { get; set; }
    public EngineModel EngineModel { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string BMSWorkorder { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is Required")]
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string OpenedBy { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Opened Date is Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? OpenedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ClosedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ClosedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Caller First Name is Required")]
    public string CallerFirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Caller Last Name is Required")]
    public string CallerLastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Qualified is Required")]
    public string Qualified { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ESN is Required")]
    public string ESN { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mileage is Required")]
    public string Mileage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateInService { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ESTR { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "EDS is Required")]
    public string EDS { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string GensetSerialNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string GensetModelNumber { get; set; }

    //child Case Notes records
    public virtual ICollection<CaseNotes> CaseNotes { get; set; }

    //child case attachment records
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    //child case complaint records
    public virtual ICollection<CaseComplaint> CaseComplaint { get; set; }

    //tracking fields
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

A Case can have many CaseNotes, Attachments, and CaseComplaints. Foreign Keys are Technicians, Customers, and EngineModel.

Up until today, all was well with Add, and Edits with this model. Now, out of the blue I get
"*A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.*" 
only when trying to update a case record on the Edit view. A create and insert is fine since all required fields are filled.
Why would this just start happening. FYI, If I inspect the model just be for I call context.SaveChanges, I notice that all the data looks right, FK values are filled in, however the data in the navigation property for the foreign key class (Technicians) almost seems like it thinks I am trying to insert a new record in those classes...

Here are my controller Edit actions:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Cases cases = db.Cases.Find(id);
        db.Entry(cases).Reference(x => x.Customer).Load();
        db.Entry(cases).Collection(x => x.CaseComplaint).Load();
        db.Entry(cases).Collection(x => x.CaseNotes).Load();
        db.Entry(cases).Reference(x => x.Technicians).Load();

        GetCaseCategoryLookup(cases.CaseCategoryID);
        GetEngineModelLookup(cases.EngineModelID);
        GetTechnicianLookup(cases.TechnicianID);
        GetQualifiedList(cases.Qualified);
        GetCaseStatusList(cases.CaseStatus);

        return View(cases);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Cases/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Cases cases)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        AppHelpers help = new AppHelpers();

            if (cases.CaseStatus == "CLOSED")
                {
                cases.ClosedBy = "USER";
                cases.ClosedDate = help.GetEasternTime();
                }
            cases.ModifiedBy = "USER";
            cases.ModifiedOn = help.GetEasternTime();

            db.Entry(cases).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: "*however the data in the navigation property almost seems like it thinks I am trying to insert a new record in those classes*": So, then it's a view and model binding question or where does the navigation property value come from?

Comment: I am a noob so you will have to bear with me. The properties above Technicians and Customers, and EngineModel are supposed to just allow me to display the child data but it seems like they are being marked modified right along with the cases class.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you can show the post action and how you process the data up to SaveChanges.

Comment: The navigation properties will create child records on a save, since there is a FK constraint.  No FK value and you get a RI error.  For example: the TechnicianID must correspond to an existing technician, if it does not, EF will attempt to create one for you.

Comment: @Maess, that is the thing. On my create view for cases, I do select a valid technician, and I can see the proper technician id when I edit the record. So the technician id corresponds to a valid technician.

Comment: @Slauma - I added more info about the relationships and added controller actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to explain what the exception means:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   values that define the referential constraints are not consistent
>   between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Principal object in your controller post action is `cases.Technicians`, the dependent is `cases`. The "property values that define the referential constraints" are the foreign key in the dependent object, that is `cases.TechnicianID`, and on the other side the primary key of the principal, that is `cases.Technicians.TechnicianID`.

The exception says that those two values are different: `cases.TechnicianID != cases.Technicians.TechnicianID` but they must be the same when you update the entity.

I don't know what your view is exactly supposed to do. Can you only edit the `cases` entity or also the `cases.Technicians` properties? Or can you only assign a new existing technician to `cases`? If the latter is the case I'm worndering why the model binder creates a `cases.Technicians` instance because there shouldn't be any form fields that hold properties of the `cases.Technicians`. To assign another existing technician it should be enough to have the foreign key `cases.TechnicianID` bound to a form field.

In any case you need to ensure that either `cases.TechnicianID` and `cases.Technicians.TechnicianID` have the same value or that `cases.Technicians` is `null`. It depends on what the view is supposed to do and what data you need to update - only `cases` properties or `cases.Technicians` properties as well.

Comment: thanks for your time. The view is basically to add and edit cases. An existing technician (technicianid) can be selected by dropdown and associated with the case. The reason I was using the cases.Technicians property was to display technician info on the case. So, being new to EF I am a little confused as to having to ensure the TechnicianID and cases.Technicians.TechnicianID are the same. I don't want any updated down to cases.Technicians from the case views.

Comment: @Ryan: You can probably solve the problem then by just setting `cases.Technicians` to `null` at the beginning of the post action. But it's a hack and it is strange that the `cases.Technicians` is not `null` and the `cases.Technicians.TechnicianID` is wrong. BTW: In most cases the better way is to use ViewModels for an MVC view and not the entities directly. Your ViewModel contains the properties that are supposed to be edited and in the post action you map the viewmodel that is posted back to the entity in a way that exactly the properties get updated you need.

Comment: I think rather than a hack I would prefer to do it the right way, don't you think? Will you monitor this thread while I learn about how to use a view model? It does seem strange that a simple operation like associating a parent record with a child would be so problematic.